# generic relation setting content_object with unsaved model

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

Say I have the following model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Bar(models.Model):
    baz = models.BooleanField()
```

then run the following code:

```
f = Foo(content_object=Bar(baz=False))
print f.content_object
```

what I would expect to see is something like:

```
<Bar: Bar object>
```

but instead it seems as if it's empty...  why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content_object` has to be split into `content_type` and `object_id`. And until you save the object into the database there is no `object_id` available. Therefore you have to save it first - like Sandip suggested. You can do it in a shorter form as well: `Baz.objects.create(baz=False)`

Comment: I was hoping to have an easy way to "preview" a selection before saving, but I guess I'll have to find some way to work around this little annoying fact.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following:

```
b=Bar(baz=False)
b.save()
f = Foo(content_object=b)
f.content_object
```

This gives the desired result for you.